# VS2022 + Net Maui Blazor - Start with/without debugging causes devenv.exe to crash

Tags: c#, blazor, visual-studio-2022, maui, .net-7.0

Running a Net Maui blazor hybrid app in Net core 7 causes VS 2022 to close without error

After reviewing event viewer there are 2 errors when the crash occurs

1. .Net runtime

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Deployment.ReparsePoint.GetTarget(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Deployment.DebugLogger, System.String, Boolean ByRef)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Deployment.PackageManagerOperations.TranslatePackageInfo(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Deployment.PackageManagerOperations.TranslatePackageInfoForInstalledPackages(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package>, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Deployment.AppxLayoutManager.CheckPackageLayoutState(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Deployment.DeployPackageName, System.String)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Deployment.DeploymentDriver+<ConsumeRecipeAsync>d__133.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

2. Application error

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 17.5.33209.295, time stamp: 0x20c46274
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00007ff9aacefb24
Faulting process ID: 0x50a4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d92853f93d94de
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report ID: 783eb4ba-2b16-40ff-830a-39d2611476f1
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I've tried to catch an error dump but with VS closing it detaches from the process before catching.

Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this issue occuring all day.
Not sure if it was due to me running it in administrator but, I ran the exe directly from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe' opened my project and it build/ran without VS closing.